# unable to resolve "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index" error

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

here is the jsp code which tries to fetch password from a table

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsn2");

String U=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");
String query="select pwd from img_pwd where uname='"+U+"'";

Statement s=con.createStatement();
ResultSet r= s.executeQuery(query);
String pas="";
 if(r.next())
        {
             pas=r.getString(2);
        }

con.close();
```

and the table "img_pwd" in the database goes like this--

1. (uname,nvarchar(50)
2. (pwd,nvarchar(20))

Hence as described in the question title, i get the error--**java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index**

**NOTE:** i have come to know that there is a problem with my resultset code but i am unable to figure it out.

Can anybody Guide me???
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is selecting one field:

```
String query="select pwd from img_pwd where uname='"+U+"'";
```

But this line is looking for field #2 (and you're only SELECTing one).

```
pas=r.getString(2);
```

Change it to this, instead:

```
pas=r.getString(1);
```

For reference, here is the [Java doc on the ResultSet interface's getString method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29).

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
>   Parameters:
>   columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

Comment: thanks it worked :) Unfortunately i tried replacing 1 with 2 before also, but was getting null-pointer-exception...
Nevertheless, it worked...!!!